# Python Pandas Calculate average days between dates

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, group-by, average

Working with the following python pandas dataframe df:

```
Customer_ID | Transaction_ID
ABC            2016-05-06-1234
ABC            2017-06-08-3456
ABC            2017-07-12-5678
ABC            2017-12-20-6789
BCD            2016-08-23-7891
BCD            2016-09-21-2345
BCD            2017-10-23-4567
```

The date is unfortunately hidden in the transaction_id string. I edited the dataframe this way.

```
#year of transaction
df['year'] = df['Transaction_ID'].astype(str).str[:4]

#date of transaction
df['date'] = df['Transaction_ID'].astype(str).str[:10]

#format date
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

#calculate visit number per year
df['visit_nr_yr'] = df.groupby(['Customer_ID', 'year']).cumcount()+1
```

Now the df looks like this:

```
Customer_ID | Transaction_ID    | year  | date        |visit_nr_yr 
ABC            2016-05-06-1234    2016    2016-05-06    1            
ABC            2017-06-08-3456    2017    2017-06-08    1            
ABC            2017-07-12-5678    2017    2017-07-12    2            
ABC            2017-12-20-6789    2017    2017-12-20    3            
BCD            2016-08-23-7891    2016    2016-08-23    1            
BCD            2016-09-21-2345    2016    2016-09-21    2            
BCD            2017-10-23-4567    2017    2017-10-23    1
```

I need to calculate the following:

- What's the average days between visits by visit (so between 1&2 and between 2&3)
- What's the average days between visits in general

First I would like to include the following column "days_between_visits_by year" (math to be done by Customer_ID):

```
Customer_ID|Transaction_ID  |year| date       |visit_nr_yr|days_bw_visits_yr 
ABC         2016-05-06-1234  2016  2016-05-06   1             NaN
ABC         2017-06-08-3456  2017  2017-06-08   1             NaN
ABC         2017-07-12-5678  2017  2017-07-12   2             34
ABC         2017-12-20-6789  2017  2017-12-20   3             161
BCD         2016-08-23-7891  2016  2016-08-23   1             NaN
BCD         2016-09-21-2345  2016  2016-09-21   2             29
BCD         2017-10-23-4567  2017  2017-10-23   1             NaN
```

Please note that I avoided 0s on purpose and kept the Nans, in case somebody had two visits on the same day.

Next I want to calculate the average days between visits by visit (so between 1&2 and between 2&3 within a year). Looking for this output:

```
avg_days_bw_visits_1_2 | avg_days_bw_visits_2_3
31.5                     161
```

Finally, I want to calculate the average days between visits in general:

```
output: 203.8 
#the days between visits are 398,34,161,29,397 and the average of those 
 numbers is 203.8
```

I'm stuck with at the how to create the column "days_bw_visits_yr".
Nans have to be excluded from the math.

Comment: Can you post your desired (end) data set?

Comment: @MaxU, the dataframe with the column days_bw_visits_yr , is the desired end data set - the two other calculations are then done on that dataset, but will not be added into the dataframe, since their are aggregated averages; thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get previous visit date (grouped by customer and year) by shifting the "date" column down by 1:

```
df['previous_visit'] = df.groupby(['Customer_ID', 'year'])['date'].shift()
```

From this, days between visits is simply the difference:

```
df['days_bw_visits'] = df['date'] - df['previous_visit']
```

To calculate mean, convert the date delta object to days:

```
df['days_bw_visits'] = df['days_bw_visits'].apply(lambda x: x.days)
```

Average days between visits:

```
df.groupby('visit_nr_yr')['days_bw_visits'].agg('mean')

df['days_bw_visits'].mean()
```

Comment: Thank you very much - testing this solution right now; the shift option sounds great

Comment: I unfortunately get the 'Dataerror: error message No numeric types to aggregate" I think it is related to the date not being a date type?

Comment: For anyone looking at this as a solution. Make sure you sort the date column before doing `shift()`. so the first line of code should be `df = df.sort_values(by='date)` then continue on with parasu's code. I just spent 30 mins trying to figure out what was wrong with the code. My df was 99% sorted already, except for a few rows which caused some weird negative values.

Comment: What does this part do? df.groupby('visit_nr_yr')['days_bw_visits'].agg('mean')

Answer (score 1):

Source DF:

```
In [96]: df
Out[96]:
  Customer_ID   Transaction_ID
0         ABC  2016-05-06-1234
1         ABC  2017-06-08-3456
2         ABC  2017-07-12-5678
3         ABC  2017-12-20-6789
4         BCD  2016-08-23-7891
5         BCD  2016-09-21-2345
6         BCD  2017-10-23-4567
```

Solution:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Transaction_ID.str[:10])
df['visit_nr_yr'] = df.groupby(['Customer_ID', df['Date'].dt.year]).cumcount()+1
df['days_bw_visits_yr'] = \
    df.groupby(['Customer_ID', df['Date'].dt.year])['Date'].diff().dt.days
```

Result:

```
In [98]: df
Out[98]:
  Customer_ID   Transaction_ID       Date  visit_nr_yr  days_bw_visits_yr
0         ABC  2016-05-06-1234 2016-05-06            1                NaN
1         ABC  2017-06-08-3456 2017-06-08            1                NaN
2         ABC  2017-07-12-5678 2017-07-12            2               34.0
3         ABC  2017-12-20-6789 2017-12-20            3              161.0
4         BCD  2016-08-23-7891 2016-08-23            1                NaN
5         BCD  2016-09-21-2345 2016-09-21            2               29.0
6         BCD  2017-10-23-4567 2017-10-23            1                NaN
```

Comment: Thank you @MaxU ; I follow your steps exactly but for the last row for days_bw_visits_yr, I get this error AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that, in addition to getting the time diff between last purchase

```
df['previous_visit'] = df.groupby(['Customer_ID', 'year'])['date'].shift()
df['days_bw_visits'] = df['date'] - df['previous_visit'] 
df['days_bw_visits'] = df['days_bw_visits'].apply(lambda x: x.days)
```

you should make sure your dates are sorted by your group value prior to executing .shift() to avoid negative days_bw_visits

```
df = df.sort_values(['Customer_ID', 'DATE_D'])
```