# Pandas: How to I find the average number of days between visits, grouped by customer?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

In Python/Pandas, I want to create a column in my dataframe that shows the average number of days between customer visits at a venue. That is, for each customer, what are the average number of days between that customer's visits?

Data looks like

[Image of My Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPFMU.png)

Sorry I'm really inexperienced and don't know how to type the data up other than this. I am following the solution in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241221/python-pandas-calculate-average-days-between-dates), except that that person wanted the average number of days between visits in general, and I want days between visits for each customer. Thank you.

Comment: You can copy paste the data and click `{}` in the edit options of the textbox that you are entering your question.

Answer (score 0):

For each customer, you would need to have `date_of_first_visit` and `date_of_most_recent_visit` as well as the `number_of_visits`. Then the equation would be something like

`days_since_first = date_of_most_recent_visit - date_of_first_visit`

`average_days_between = days_since_first / number_of_visits`

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```
avg_days_btw_visit_p_customer = df.groupby('CustomerID', as_index=False)['Days_Btw_Visit'].agg('mean')
```

This will return the folowing:

```
     CustomerID     Days_Btw_Visit
0             1                9.5

1             2               29.0

2             3                NaN

3             4                3.0
```

Also, if you want to get rid of the `NaN`, you can use:

```
avg_days_btw_visit_p_customer = avg_days_btw_visit_p_customer.dropna()
```

Comment: Thank you. I was stuck a little on how to get the output to append to the original data frame as a new column. I didn’t find a way to directly append to the original data frame, but by making the output a new dataframe I was able to merge with the original dataframe—merging on customer ID.